# Show middle hierarchy in Excel treemap?

Tags: microsoft-excel, powershell, charts

I have a CSV with filesystem data; file paths and size. I've created a treemap chart from this data, but the problem is that the treemap doesn't seem to take hierarchy into account. Each data point, no matter how deep in the hierarchy, is shown at the top level. I'd like it to appear more like the chart in WinDirStat/KDirStat, where each point is grouped hierarchically, by subfolders.

Full story: I'm trying to generate a chart like WinDirStat does, silently and from the command line. I have a PowerShell script that generates the CSV just fine. But if there's a better way, I'm open to it.

Answer (score 0):

Data for the treemap chart (new in Excel 2016) must be arranged from broad to specific, left to right, each text value in its own column. Read more [here.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-treemap-chart-in-Office-2016-dfe86d28-a610-4ef5-9b30-362d5c624b68)

The treemap charts are not as detailed as the WinDirStat visualisation, though.

Quoting from the Microsoft page:

> Treemap charts are good for comparing proportions within the
>   hierarchy, however, treemap charts aren't great at showing
>   hierarchical levels between the largest categories and each data
>   point.

Comment: That doesn't help me show the actual tree. I've added a request on uservoice: https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304921-excel-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/15547215-use-hierarchal-data-in-treemap